# Using SMTPS or SMTP with STARTTLS with OpenDJ for sending notifications

Tags: email, opendj, opends

Is it possible to use SMTP over TLS or SMTP with STARTTLS in OpenDJ settings for sending alert notifications.

I was able to find a config to specify SMTP config as global configuration with `--set smtp-server:smtp.example.com:port` but was not able to find if it supports secure SMTP or not.

Does it automatically detects secure SMTP if server supports it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question would be best answered on the OpenDJ mailing lists or forums, but since I'm at it, the answer is not with the current version. 
OpenDJ is an open source project and contributions are welcome !